# Identify a cartoon TV show featuring exoskeleton beaming tech

Tags: story-identification

I remember watching a cartoon TV show in early 00’s which featured a military organisation having exoskeleton beaming tech. Here are the features of this unique tech:

- There were Star Trek transporter style pads. You needed to stand on it to get exoskeleton beamed on your body.
- There was one instance in which the exoskeleton was beamed directly from the satellite without the need of pads.

One other detail I remember: Three protagonists used to get army, navy and air force style exoskeletons. Means, air force style exoskeleton could make the person wearing it fly, for example. I don’t remember any other detail.

Can you please identify the TV show?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This sounds like it could be [Centurions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Centurions_(TV_series)) but it's from the 1980s. The main team includes three main characters with exoskeletons, each one representing air, land or naval warfare.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. This is the one. I recognised the characters.